# Create DataFrame from RDD of key value with list as value

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a rdd as below

`rdd_1 = ['"columns":["date","appname","appenv","appstate"]']`

I want to convert it to a dataframe like below

```
+---------+
| columns |
+---------+
|date     |
|appname  |
|appenv   |
|appstate |
+---------+
```

What I tried:
I tired to create a schema as below and use that to create the dataframe,but that did not work

```
rdd_1_schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField('columns',ArrayType(StringType()))
    ])
```

The error output with the schema is below

```
rdd1.toDF(schema=rdd_1_schema).show()
```

Error:

```
TypeError: StructType can not accept object '"columns": in type <type 'str'>
```

2nd Try: I tried using flatmap

```
rdd1.flatMap(lambda x: map(lambda e: (x[0], e), x[1])).toDF().show()
```

but it takes each string as elements of list e.g of the output below

```
+---+---+
| _1| _2|
+---+---+
| ''|  c|
+---+---+
```

Comment: hi there, so you are trying to create a new schema from the list `["date","appname","appenv","appstate"]`?

Comment: @Alexandros Biratsis no I am trying to create the dataframe from that rdd, what I tried with putting some schema, but that is not working. I have provided that details

Comment: toDf function does not expect a schema but a string list containing the column names

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark RDD to DataFrame python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39699107/spark-rdd-to-dataframe-python)

Comment: It is different from that,though its creation of a Dataframe but the problem here is different

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to create a spark dataframe from an RDD which has a single column with string values in it and this RDD comes from a dictionary?

Comment: RDD does not have column its a key value with a list being the value which needs to be converted as Row and RDD does not return the key correctly though visually it looks as key value pair

Comment: Your question is not clear. Provide an example of what you are trying to get. Looks like rdd_1 is the logical schema of your dataframe and not the rdd itself. An RDD contains some data and does have columns indeed! See here: https://runawayhorse001.github.io/LearningApacheSpark/rdd.html