# How to read Json Gzip files from S3 into List?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have multiple files in S3.

```
s3 = boto3.client("s3")
paginator = s3.get_paginator("list_objects_v2")
for page in paginator.paginate(Bucket='cw-milenko-tests', Prefix='Json_gzips'):
    contents = page["Contents"]
    for c in contents:
        if (c['Key']).startswith('Json_gzips/tick_calculated_3'):
            print(c['Key'])
```

Output

```
Json_gzips/tick_calculated_3_2020-05-27T00-05-51.json.gz
Json_gzips/tick_calculated_3_2020-05-27T00-13-23.json.gz
Json_gzips/tick_calculated_3_2020-05-27T00-17-36.json.gz
Json_gzips/tick_calculated_3_2020-05-27T00-28-10.json.gz
Json_gzips/tick_calculated_3_2020-05-27T00-30-43.json.gz
Json_gzips/tick_calculated_3_2020-05-27T00-34-56.json.gz
Json_gzips/tick_calculated_3_2020-05-27T00-38-29.json.gz
```

I want to real all these files into Spark Data Frame,then perform union and save that as a single parquet file. I already asked [define schema for PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62872164/how-to-define-schema-for-pyspark-createdataframerdd-schema) and got usefull answer.
How should i edit my code

```
data = spark.read.json(c['Key'])
```

data should be saved to big_data =[data1,data2,...]

That would enable me union.

```
bigdf = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, big_data)
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only this data in the S3 bucket, you can read them directly:

```py
data = spark.read.json('s3:/.../Json_gzips/')
```

if we want to read only some data, and we have a list of files/URLs, then we can do following:

```
from functools import reduce
lst=['s3:/....', 's3:/...']
dfs = [spark.read.json(file) for file in lst]
udfs = reduce(lambda df1, df2: df1.union(df2), dfs)
```

How it works:

- first line imports `reduce` function that simplifies code
- second line defines a list of resources
- third - generates a dataframe for every item in list
- last one - perform pairwise `union` operation on all dataframes

There are caveats here that needs to be taken into account:

- this specific code relies on the schema auto-detection done by `spark.read.json`, and this may lead to the having dataframes with different schema if some data is missing in some files
- schema for all dataframes participating in union should be the same, otherwise you'll get error

But we can workaround this by providing schema explicitly when reading the data.  I often use following "hack" - put one or two samples into a separate file, and read it by Spark, and use the inferred schema for enforcing the schema during reading - it will be also faster, as schema is already provided.  For example, how it could be done:

```py
>>> lst = ["file1", "file2", "file3"]
# we're reading the data without schema
>>> dfs = [spark.read.json(file) for file in lst]
# we get different lengths of the schemas
>>> map(lambda df: len(df.schema), dfs)
[28, 28, 27]
# we're getting error when trying to do union
>>> udfs = reduce(lambda df1, df2: df1.union(df2), dfs)
```

we reading with enforcing the schema:

```py
>>> sample_schema = spark.read.json("sample_file.json").schema
>>> dfs = [spark.read.schema(sample_schema).json(file) for file in lst]
# all lengths are the same
>>> map(lambda df: len(df.schema), dfs)
[28, 28, 28]
# and union works
>>> udfs = reduce(lambda df1, df2: df1.union(df2), dfs)
```

Comment: @Djikii I've updated the answer with example how to enforce the schema